# The meaning of ontology in computer science

Tags: artificial-intelligence, information-theory, modelling

I am reading a paper and ran into this word `Ontology-based`, What does it really mean? I did searching about it but still ambiguous to me, can someone elaborate this concept with an example?

Thank you

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on the context?

Comment: It's part of an area known as *knowledge representation* (KR). See [this](http://cui.unige.ch/isi/icle-wiki/_media/cours:sw:gen_intro_ontologies.pdf) for example.

Comment: What paper is this? The answer to your question is probably in the paper that mentions "ontology-based" and without further context it is hard to help here... Ontologies are simply logical theories, therefore, you can consider any (typically first order) logical theory as an example. "Ontology-based" can then mean anything that is done together with ontologies. A common usage is in ontology based data access, which is nothing else but querying data sources (say databases) with the help of  ontological rules.